# How to integrate Avaya CTI with Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-12, avaya, avaya-dmcc-.net

I want to integrate `Avaya Cti` with `odoo12`. Anyone please suggest me a way to integrate or any integrated module or a python library.
I'll be very thankful.

Comment: There is an Odoo to Asterisk connector (https://github.com/OCA/connector-telephony) and Odoo to RingCentral connector (https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/12.0/ringcentral/). Is that close to what you need?

Comment: I need `Avaya` API link and documentation...